# Sunspot Solr: Match multiple attributes together from a same has_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

Let's pretend we have two users,

**User A**, with:

- skill of 'Ruby' and experience_years of '5'
- skill of 'HTML' and experience_years of '7'

**User B**, with:

- skill of 'Ruby' and experience_years of '2'
- skill of 'HTML' and experience_years of '5'

I only want to match **User A**, that is, the user with 5 years of Ruby experience.

The controller and model code below matches both User A and B, because the `skill` and `experience_years` is evaluated separately and both users have 'Ruby' and '5', just not together.

How do I write the controller (or model) part to only match User A?

**Models**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_skills

  searchable do
    text :skill do
      user_skills.map { |r| r.skill.name }
    end
    text :experience_years do
      user_skills.pluck(:experience_years)
    end
  end
end

class UserSkill < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :skill
end

class Skill < ApplicationRecord
end
```

**Controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    sunspot = User.search do
      fulltext 'Ruby' do
        fields(:skill)
      end
      fulltext '31' do
        fields(:experienceYears)
      end
    end

    @users = sunspot.results
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a dynamic integer.

Model (inside searchable block):

```
# skill + experienceYears composite field:
dynamic_integer :skill_composite do
  if skills
    skills.inject({}) do |hash, e|
      hash.merge(e.skill.skill_code => e.experience_years)
    end
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
with(skill_code).equal_to experience_years
```

Note the use of `skill_code` instead of `name`, this is because special characters like spaces in a string will cause troubles. `skill_code` is a sort of parameterized value of name in this case.